# Расширение для chrome. Внедрение js

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Есть некий сайт. Назовем его *mysite.ru*

Так вот, я хочу выполнять некоторый функционал на сайте и не хочу делать это вручную. поэтому я написал скрипт JS, который запускал на странице и он отлично работал.

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = '\
<button onclick="start()" id="playBut" style="margin: 5px">play</button>\
';

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(node);

function start(){
    // My code here
};
```

и все замечательно работает. Вот только мне надоело постоянно запускать код при обновлении страницы, поэтому я решил создать расширение для браузера. Полазил по хабру и собрал вот что

```
 {
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "MyExt",
   "version": "1.0.0.16",
   "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://mysite.ru/*" // Разрешить расширению обращаться к указанному адресу
 ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://mysite.ru/*" ],
      "js": [ "MyScript.js" ]
    }
  ],

      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "MyExt"
    }
}
```

В файле *MyScript.js* как раз тот скрипт, что я описал в начале.

Но проблема в том, что когда расширение запускается на нужном мне сайте, кнопочка появляется, а вот функция `start()` не выполняется. В консоли вижу

Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Ну так функция start у вас находится не в документе, а в расширении. Используйте нормальные обработчики с использованием .addEventListener

Comment: @Etki, немного не понял. Функция не в расширении, а в файле, который расширение подключает к сайтам, которые совпадают с matches. По крайней мере я так думал. Можете подробнее рассказать про этот EventListener?

Comment: @Etki, там на самом деле не просто обработка клика... там чуть сложнее. Функция `start()` запускает функцию `F()`, которая запускает сама себя рекурсивно. То есть если даже я привяжу через этот листенер свою функцию, то таким же образом потеряется функция `F`. поэтому мне надо именно инъекцию сделать

Comment: не потеряется. start будет видеть весь свой контекст

Comment: @Etki, ну хорошо если так... так что сделать то надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас вы предлагаете браузеру примерно такой сценарий:

"При нажатии на кнопку найти функцию, содержащуюся в переменной `start` и выполнить ее"

Так как функция start находится в файлах расширения, она отсутствует в документе, в контексте которого выполняется поиск, поэтому браузер ничего не может найти.

Выход из этого довольно простой - вместо того, чтобы заставлять браузер обращаться к функции по имени, просто повесить ее обработчиком, передав целиком и избавившись от этих проблем.

```
var button = document.getElementById('playBut');
button.addEventListener('click', start, false);
```

В этом случае барузер сразу получит функцию, которую ему надо вызывать при нажатии на кнопку, а она, находясь в файлах расширения, будет выполняться в контексте этого расширения, позволяя вам обращаться к иным фукнциям расширения.

Comment: Извините за тупость, но в функции `F()` есть вот такая строка `var obj = $.parseJSON(http.responseText);` которая не работает. полагаю, это потому, что в контексте функции нет jQuery. Но на самом сайте то она подключена. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: а нельзя ли просто встроить все мои скрипты на сайт, как я это делал используя `javascript:(MY CODE)` в адресной строке или через консоль отладчика? Почему с расширениями так сложно это сделать?

Comment: как jquery подключать, не знаю, но вопрос должен быть распространенный. вы можете попробовать инжектнуть свой скрипт новым тегом `<script>` на страницу